# Creating whatsapp type tip styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to follow this code on calculating tips - but I do not know how to create this tip at the top left/right like the whatsapp style. I've seen nothing like this particular method or explanation on how these shapes are created.

[image]

I've tried something like this but then I loose the border-radius

```css
.arrow {
  --a: 15px; /* control the arrow shape */

  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  padding-left: var(--a); /* or padding-right */
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,var(--a) 100%,var(--a) var(--a))
  /* x,y --> update all the x to (100% - x) to get the right */
}
```

```html
                                <div class="arrow">
                                  contents
                                </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4azhk38o/

```css
.bubble {
  --r: 25px; /* the radius */
  --t: 30px; /* the size of the tail */
  
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: calc(2*var(--r)/3);
  -webkit-mask: 
    radial-gradient(var(--t) at var(--_d) 0,#0000 98%,#000 102%) 
      var(--_d) 100%/calc(100% - var(--r)) var(--t) no-repeat,
    conic-gradient(at var(--r) var(--r),#000 75%,#0000 0) 
      calc(var(--r)/-2) calc(var(--r)/-2) padding-box, 
    radial-gradient(50% 50%,#000 98%,#0000 101%) 
      0 0/var(--r) var(--r) space padding-box;
  background: #1384C5;
  color: #fff;
}
.left {
  --_d: 0%;
  border-left: var(--t) solid #0000;
  margin-right: var(--t);
  place-self: start;
}
.right {
  --_d: 100%;
  border-right: var(--t) solid #0000;
  margin-left: var(--t);
  place-self: end;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble left">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt </div>
<div class="bubble right">Ok, Thank you</div>
<div class="bubble left"> ut labore et dolore magna </div>
<div class="bubble right">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `:after` to create a border around empty content. Basically followed [tooltip example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp).

```css
.left-message {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(250, 230, 175);
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 50%;
}
.left-message:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(250, 230, 175) rgb(250, 230, 175) transparent transparent;
}
.right-message {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(234, 250, 175);
  border-radius: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.right-message:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(234, 250, 175) transparent transparent rgb(234, 250, 175);
}
```

```html
<div class="left-message">
  Hello World
</div>
<div class="right-message">
  Hi there!
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this looks very clean. I am just confused about how one goes about doing a polyclip in the other approached.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j70hzLdu/1/  jsfiddle of it

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "polyclip". Can you please explain?

Comment: there just seem to be various methods like the one below that use math to create the polygon shape - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899997/how-to-create-a-curved-speech-bubble

Comment: @TheOldCounty, unfortunately I cannot understand it either, the answer link you shared doesn't really explain anything.

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SG3c.png)

please replace this css with your css

```
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(var(--t) at var(--_d) 100%, #0000 98%, #000 102%) var(--_d) 0%/calc(100% - var(--r)) var(--t) no-repeat, conic-gradient(at var(--r) var(--r),#000 75%,#0000 0) calc(var(--r)/-2) calc(var(--r)/-2) padding-box, radial-gradient(50% 50%,#000 98%,#0000 101%) 0 0/var(--r) var(--r) space padding-box;
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the question. Code-only answers are not good answers

Comment: check screen short, why are you doing down point in my answer ?

Comment: Please have a look at [answer]. Furthermore you shouldn't share code in an image

Comment: you check first my answer screen shot

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: please explain where i wronged answer

Comment: that has a slight lip and only shows the left aligned variant - could you show your answer to solve both situations and explain where in the math this is handled